# Extract SOAP body from Envolope request inside azure logic app action

Tags: xml, azure, xpath, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic app (LA) that have an http trigger. To the LA, I send a SOAP request similar to this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"></SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <tns:Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:tns="http://test.com">
      <name>AAAA</name>
      <id>1234</id>
      <OrderType>new</OrderType>
    </tns:Order>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I want to create another action in the LA that extract the Envelope body to me. i.e. I want to only get this:

```xml
<tns:Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tns="http://test.com">
    <name>AAAA</name>
    <id>1234</id>
    <OrderType>new</OrderType>
</tns:Order>
```

I tried to have a compose action with the following function:

```java
xpath(triggerBody(), '/*[local-name()=''Envelope'']/*[local-name()=''Body'']/*[local-name=''Order'']')
```

as you can see here:
[image]

but this reutn to me an error:
[image]

Any idea for how to solve this problem?
I have tried to remove all the namespaces and it seems that it works but not when having namespaecs

Comment: Do you need it in XML?

Comment: Hi @Skin!
yes, I need to have it as xml with the order namespaces too (tns)!

Comment: @ibda can you check below answer as I have changed it back to xml using ```xml(outputs('Compose_2'))```  in edit section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue with the `null` is a bit perplexing and hard for me to decipher and fix because receiving that error tells me you're not quite reading the incoming request properly (or something) but, if I load your XML into a variable and then extract the contents of `tns:Order`, I can get it to work and this approach doesn't require you to traverse down the hierarchy using a fully qualified approach.

**Flow**

[image: Flow]

This is the expression in the second step ...

`first(xpath(xml(variables('XML')), '//*[local-name()="Order"]'))`

**Result**

[image: Result]

Comment: Hi @Skin! This solution looks great! I get the same result as you both inside variables and in compose actions. I have found my problem too, I had an empty space in the incoming message that has cause all the errors. Thank you very much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

**`Design:`**

```
json(xml(triggerBody()))
```

[image]

Then used `outputs('Compose')['SOAP-ENV:Envelope']['SOAP-ENV:Body']['tns:Order']` :

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`CodeView:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@json(xml(triggerBody()))",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@outputs('Compose')['SOAP-ENV:Envelope']['SOAP-ENV:Body']['tns:Order']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

**`Edit:`**

If you want output in xml:

`xml(outputs('Compose_2'))`

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`Codeview:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@json(xml(triggerBody()))",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@outputs('Compose')['SOAP-ENV:Envelope']['SOAP-ENV:Body']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_3": {
                "inputs": "@xml(outputs('Compose_2'))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RithwikBojja! but this will return the data as list of items, I need to keep it as xml

Comment: @ibda, See at end, I have changed it back to xml using ```xml(outputs('Compose_2'))```

Comment: @ibda check in Edit heading in answer

Comment: Hi @RithwikBojja ! I am sorry to not accept the answer but I was getting different erros with this answer. first in compose1: "Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose_Rath1' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'json' parameter is not valid. The provided XML value cannot be parsed: 'Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no whitespace characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 2, position 3.'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#parse for usage details.'.
"

Comment: I have also tried to remove the first line in the xml input, i.e.: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> and when I do compose1 works but compose3 fail with this error: Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose_Rath3' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'xml' parameter is not valid. The provided value cannot be converted to XML: 'JSON root object has property '@xmlns:xsi' that will be converted to an attribute. A root object cannot have any attribute properties. Consider specifying a DeserializeRootElementName. Path 'outputs.@xmlns:xsi'

Comment: You shouldnt remove any headers, and I have taken your input as mine and got results , you can clearly see in screen shots too.